Messaging.SingleEmailMessage does not send emails using apex
I have tried executing the following code in the anonymous window in the developer console and the email is sent. But when I execute it via a list view button it does not send an email.
There are no errors when the code is run. The Deliverability is set to all email. I have also tested sending emails using Test Deliverability and I receive them. The logs also show that emails have been sent.
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    EmailTemplate et = [SELECT Id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName = 'Work_in_Progress'];
    System.debug(et);
    for(Contact currentContact : emailList){

        if(currentContact.Email != null){
            List<string> toAddress = new List<string>();
            toAddress.add(currentContact.Email);

            
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            email.setTemplateId(et.Id);         
            email.setToAddresses(toAddress);
            email.setTargetObjectId(currentContact.Id);

            emails.add(email);
        }
    }
    
     system.debug('send email to ' + emails);
     Messaging.sendEmail(emails);


from which query emailList is coming from? have you checked by debugging the scope or query?

Hi, thanks for the reply. It is a list of contact emails passed to the method. I am not sure what you mean by scope or query or how to check this
